# can I get two values at time in a comprehension list?

Tags: python, pandas

Can I have a list getting `[y, z]` at the same time with a comprehension list like this?

`default_list = [y,z for x,y,z in df_acc[['acc_number', 'password', 'server']].values if x == default_acc]`

The above code gives me a syntax error. What should be the correct one?

Comment: maybe `[[y,z] for x,y,z in ..` is what you want?

Comment: that works, but gives me `[[y,z]]`

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you will need nested `for`:

```
>>> default_list = [elem for x,y,z in df_acc[['acc_number', 'password', 'server']].values
                         for elem in (x, y) if x == default_acc]
```

But if it is a DataFrame, then it would be more efficient to do:

```
>>> df_acc.loc[df['acc_number'].eq(default_acc), ['acc_number', 'password']].stack().tolist()
```

If you specifically want `list comprehension`, there are other options without going for nested loops, using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((y,z) 
         for x,y,z in df_acc[['acc_number', 'password', 'server']].values 
         if x == default_acc))
```

Also, if you are using pandas version 0.24.0+, when converting from `dataframe` to `numpy` array, consider switching to [`pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) as opposed to [`pandas.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values), as per `pandas` recommendation, as can be seen [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#attributes-and-underlying-data) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values)

Comment: your second solution was perfect. I prefer efficiency, although it was great to learn the comprehension solution as well.